# Does positive set theory prove the existence of a set of all ordinals and itself?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Does positive set theory [$\sf GPK^+_\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_set_theory#Axioms) prove the existence of a set $K= \{x \mid x \text { is von Neumann ordinal  } \lor x=K\}$

Comment: I would guess no, "$x$ is a von Neumann ordinal" is not positive, otherwise $\{x\mid x\text{ is a von Neumann ordinal and }\forall y∈x∀f:y\to y\;((∀z∈y∀w∈y\;f(z)=f(w)⇒z=w)⇒∀z∈y∃w∈y\;f(w)=z)\}$ would have define $ω$ in $GPK^+$ (where $f:y\to y$ is "$∀p∈f∃z∈y∃w∈y\;(p=\{\{z\},\{z,w\}\})$ and $∀z∈y∀w∈y∀u∈y\;((\{\{z\},\{z,w\}\}∈f∧\{\{z\},\{z,u\}\})⇒w=u)$")

Comment: But you have the closure schema, so just close on von Neumanns and you get a set in which all von Neumanns are elements, but I don't know if you can get that closure to be the set $K$.

Comment: The closure only gives you a minimal super-set of each class, on face value there is no reason this set won't be e.g. "all transitive sets" (I meant, there is a reason, but my point is that the closure can result with a huge set, it doesn't tells you a lot)

Comment: @Holo, yes I know, but there might be another way to do that, not just closures.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar:  also take a look at the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy entry , "Alternative Axiomatic Set Theories"  It should be helpful as well.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin, Yea! I see, it also affirms the claim of this question! Very nice. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to know that this question had been answered to the positive by the founder of $\sf GPK^+_\infty$ himself at an article of him titled: [Inconsistency of GPK + AFA](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.19960420109). At Journal Math.Log.Quart 1996: vol. 42, issue 1, page 107